# Show or hide HTML code based on URL

Tags: php, html, forms, function, url

I am working on a form and I've stumbled upon a problem. I have different users in which I want them to see different values for one of my SELECT tags; so far I am using PHP to get the URL and if $field == 'donor' then it takes off some of the options. Here's the code:

```
function defineUser($field){
    if(isset($_GET['user']) && urldecode($_GET['user'])){
        $field = urldecode($_GET['user']);
        if($field == "donor"){
            return "<p>
                    <label for=designation>Designation</label>
                    <select name='merchant_defined_field_4' id='merchant_defined_field_4' required=''>
                        <option value=''>Select...</option>
                        <option value=''>Option 1</option>
                        <option value=''>Option 2</option>
                        <option value=''>Option 3</option>
                        <option value='Other'>Option 4</option>
                    </select>
                    </p>";
        } else if ($field != "donor") {
            return "<p>
                    <label for=designation>Designation</label>
                    <select name='merchant_defined_field_4' id='merchant_defined_field_4' required=''>
                        <option value=''>...</option>
                    </select>
                    </p>";
        } else {
            return "<p>
                    <label for=designation>Designation</label>
                    <select name='merchant_defined_field_4' id='merchant_defined_field_4' required=''>
                        <option value=''>...</option>
                    </select>
                    </p>";
        }
    }
}
```

This is my function, now on the page source itself I simply have,

```
<?php echo defineUser($_GET['user']); ?>
```

My question simply is how can I get each user to see a standard options set - inside my select tag - based on the URL the user has been sent from?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking in that last question.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: Your function does not make much sense.. You pass it a param ($field) but the first thing you're doing ... you overwrite it at the 3rd line. why?

Comment: I think by "standard options" he means the last `else` where $field doesn't match the other values.

Comment: David, I reworded the question some. I am sorry for my English.

Comment: Twinfriends on the third line I was trying to get the value from the URL param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code could be simplified:

```
function defineUser() {
    $user = isset($_GET['user']) ? urldecode($_GET['user']) : null;

    switch ($user) {
        case 'donor':
            return "<p>
                    <label for=designation>Designation</label>
                    <select name='merchant_defined_field_4' id='merchant_defined_field_4' required=''>
                        <option value=''>Select...</option>
                        <option value=''>Option 1</option>
                        <option value=''>Option 2</option>
                        <option value=''>Option 3</option>
                        <option value='Other'>Option 4</option>
                    </select>
                    </p>";
            break;

        default:
            return "<p>
                    <label for=designation>Designation</label>
                    <select name='merchant_defined_field_4' id='merchant_defined_field_4' required=''>
                        <option value=''>...</option>
                    </select>
                    </p>";
    }
}
```

You don't need to pass it `$_GET['user']` since that is globally accessible, unless you're worried about dependency. Second, you were essentially repeating the same block of HTML twice in your `if else` clause, using a `switch` here makes more sense.

Comment: What do you mean about $_GET['user'] what could I use instead?

Comment: I just mean you don't have to pass it in as a parameter. Instead of `defineUser($field)` you can simply call `defineUser()`